# Node.js with struts Possible?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, struts2

Now i know i might come out to be very silly at asking this. But I am a complete newbie to node.js and i have done some reading about node.js, and so much unstructured info on the internet has only confused me further.

I have a small web application with a database and back-end Java using Struts 2.0. Now i am thinking of using node.js.

I want to introduce a chat feature in my application. I believe using socket.io will be good for that purpose. However, i don't want to change my complete back-end, as that is working really well right now. I can also use websockets using jetty and all.

Will i have to let go of the Struts framework? and can node.js also have a struts similar implementation? My only aim is having layers of abstraction that Struts provide so well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/) is a java framwork running in a java serlvet contianer (e.g. [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)).

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) is a server side JavaScript environment which is used to implement web resources.

There are fundamental differences in how this two aproaches work. But you can implement any kind of web application with both of them. However there's no direct/easy way to mix the two.

If you already have Struts2 it's most likely a good idea to stick with it.

Comment: *However there's no direct/easy way to mix the two.* - there isn't any good reason for mixing them also. ;)

Comment: @AleksandrM Why do you say so?

Comment: @sharmaRaj411: Do you have any reason for using both frameworks in same application?

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes. actually..... well, i want to introduce a chat feature in my application. I believe using socket.io will be good for that purpose. However, i don't want to change my complete back-end, as that is working really well right now. I can also use websockets using jetty and all. I am only trying to understand which approach is better.

Comment: @sharmaRaj411: You don't need node to use websockets, but you are probably need some front-end framework.

Comment: 9 examples out of 10 for demonstrating WebSockets are about a chat application. Just google "websocket chat XXXX" where XXXX is the language you prefer, and you will get a least 10 tutorials.